# How to scroll a console command output in GVim?

Tags: vim, scroll

GVim on linux

I use `:!some command` inside Vim often. I've just switched from vimx to a gvim, and there is a differences. 
I cant scroll in gvim an output, like I scroll it in vimx with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> / <kbd>d</kbd> / <kbd>f</kbd> / <kbd>b</kbd> yet?  btw, mouse wheel will also do the trick in most cases.

Comment: What's the distro you're using?  What does it show when you enter `:set scrollopt?`?

Comment: These commands are not supposed to work at a hit-enter prompt shown just after a `:!` command execution.  And what is `scrollopt` option to this problem?  That option configures scrolling behavior of `scrollbind` windows!