# How to scroll a console command output in MacVim/GVim?

Tags: macos, vim, vertical-scrolling

When I print to output of a script in VIM I can't scroll up, so I can see only the last lines. For example if this is my script:

```
for i in range(1000):
    print str(i)+"TEST"
```

And I run this command:

```
:w !python -
```

How can I scroll to see the e.g. 500TEST lines.
I've see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831379/how-to-scroll-a-console-command-output-in-gvim) question but this doesn't work for mac OSX.

Comment: @gits thanks! However there are some differences I can't find the right answer in [hot to scroll..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130722/how-to-scroll-up-to-view-the-output-of-system-command-in-vim) maybe is better the second however even there there are no useful answer, I hope I could find a better way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think MacVim/GVim's pseudo terminal is able of scrolling with the usual scrolling keys. Did you try piping your command into a pager? The following works, here:

```
:!python % | less -d
```

(edit)

`less` has *a lot* of vi-like commands. Use `/foo` to search forward, `?foo` to search backward, `50G` to jump to line 50, `<C-f>` to page down, `$ less +G` to jump directly to last line`…

`$ man less` is a surprisingly good read.

Comment: Thanks but so I can see only the first 60 lines! Strange!

Comment: `less` has a lot of vi-like commands: see `$ man less` for the complete list but you can do `gg`, `G`, `<C-f>`, `<C-d>` and so on. `less -d +G` goes straight to last line.